# Django test post in localhost AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I have a test.py file that is supposed to send a POST request to my LocalHost site (if LH doesn't work for this I can also do test on test.domain.com). However, I am not getting any new information saved in my DB. I have tried this out with GET before and it worked perfectly.

Error message in CMD:

> File "C:\Users\winkl\Desktop\VE\mysite\payment\views.py", line 36, in webhook
>       user = User.objects.POST(id=request.POST('clientAccnum'))
>   AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'POST'

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    template_name = 'payment/index.html'

    hook = Webhook()
   #ERROR MESSAGE FOR LINE BELOW
    user = User.objects.POST(id=request.POST('clientAccnum'))

    hook.user = user
    hook.clientSubacc = request.POST('clientSubacc')
    hook.eventType = request.POST('eventType')
    hook.eventGroupType = request.POST('eventGroupType')
    hook.subscriptionId = request.POST('subscriptionId')

    hook.timestamp = request.POST('timestamp')
    hook.timestamplocal = timezone.now()

    hook.save()

    user = User.objects.POST(id=request.POST('clientAccnum'))
    hook.user = user
    hook.user.profile.account_paid = hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess'
    hook.user.profile.save()

    print (hook.user, hook.clientSubacc, hook.timestamplocal)
    return render(request, template_name)
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/webhook/'
data = {'user':'11',
        'clientSubacc': '1111',
        'eventType': 'RenewalSuccess',
        'eventGroupType': 'Success',
        'subscriptionId': '12345'}

r = requests.post(url, (data))
```

Goal is to have this test post create a successful webhook which will be saved in my DB. This information updates my users account status.

Comment: Well yes, `objects` doesn't have an attribute POST. Why are you trying to use one? Have you maybe done a search and replace of `get` to `post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistype while refactoring or smth. Try using a

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))
```

to get requested user

## Adding to answer

This answer got me closer but did not 100% solve the issue.

1. Missing was the "get" in POST.get() you'll see in the OP there was only POST().
2. "user" was not a real object changed that to "clientAccnum"

Also was better to print the whole post instead of just the user. Helped me realize the second issue.

Been stuck on this forever! Thanks for the help. You got me a few steps further which lead me to the rest.

```
def webhook(request):
    template_name = 'payment/index.html'

    #print(request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))
    print(request.POST)

    hook = Webhook()
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))
    #user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user'))

    #hook.user = request.GET.get('clientAccnum')
    hook.user = user
    hook.clientSubacc = request.POST.get('clientSubacc')
    hook.eventType = request.POST.get('eventType')
    hook.eventGroupType = request.POST.get('eventGroupType')
    hook.subscriptionId = request.POST.get('subscriptionId')

    hook.timestamp = request.POST.get('timestamp')
    hook.timestamplocal = timezone.now()

    hook.save()

    user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))
    hook.user = user
    hook.user.profile.account_paid = hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess'
    hook.user.profile.save()
```

Comment: What you wrote is exactly the same as how I have it above.

Comment: @AlexWinkler don't you see the difference between `user = User.objects.POST(id=request.POST('clientAccnum'))` and `user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))`

Comment: That's weird this time I copied it and was different. Sorry, idk what I looked at before. I got an error message now "django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[08/Feb/2018 15:44:28] "POST /payment/webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 500 84939" which is odd because the test user ID does exist. Also tried it with other existing ID's just in case and same error. Any idea?

Comment: @AlexWinkler try debugging `print(request.POST.get('clientAccnum'))` and see what ID is returned. The error says you don't have this user in your DB. Are DB settings correct?

Comment: I tried several things but nothing printed in CMD. So guessing the POST call on the test.py is wrong?

Comment: @AlexWinkler well you are using correct `url` as seen here `POST /payment/webhook/ HTTP/1.1` looks like the method is correct too if you get an error when executing `user = User.objects.POST(id=request.POST('clientAccnum'))`. You should run the app separately and try to send `POST` request there while not running tests because I don't know how they are configured in your case

Comment: Cool idea @py_dude, unfortunately, it came back with the same error message.

Comment: Was thinking it may need to be an int or the query wouldn't work. But that doesn't make sense since this test using GET worked fine.

Comment: @AlexWinkler so, everything's fine?

Comment: @AlexWinkler U're welcome! My purpose was to help you understand :)